# How to access php file from another directory

Tags: php

So i am trying to access a php file in another directory, however it is not working and i think i know why, so the php file i am currently coding is in the folder `/var/www/html/faq/` and the folder that contains the files i am trying to access is in the directory `/var/www/html/engine/`.

I have not tried anything yet.

```php
<?php
ob_start();
require_once './engine/config.php';
require_once './engine/init.php';
require_once './engine/functions.php';
if (!$user -> LoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: login.php');
    die();
}
if ($user -> IsBanned($odb))
{
    header('Location: logout.php');
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: `./` refers to current directory, `../` to one level up, that's were the `engine` directory seems to be...

Answer (score 2):

You just need another dot on the directories.

require_once '../engine/config.php';

require_once '../engine/init.php';

require_once '../engine/functions.php';